# Using and comparing relative time in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, function, date, relative-date

I need to know how to do relative time in rails but not as a sentence, more like something i could do this with (when i input format like this 2008-08-05 23:48:04 -0400)

```
if time_ago < 1 hour, 3 weeks, 1 day, etc.
    execute me
end
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Basic relative time:

```
# If "time_ago" is more than 1 hour past the current time
if time_ago < 1.hour.ago
  execute_me
end
```

## Comparison:

Use a `<` to see if `time_ago` is older than `1.hour.ago`, and `>` to see if `time_ago` is more recent than `1.hour.ago`

## Combining times, and using fractional times:

You can combine times, as davidb mentioned, and do:

```
(1.day + 3.hours + 2500.seconds).ago
```

You can also do fractional seconds, like:
`0.5.seconds.ago`

There is no `.milliseconds.ago`, so if you need millisecond precision, just break it out into a fractional second. That is, 1 millisecond ago is:

```
0.001.seconds.ago
```

## .ago() in general:

Putting `.ago` at the end of just about any number will treat the number as a #of seconds.

You can even use fractions in paranthesis:

```
(1/2.0).hour.ago   # half hour ago
(1/4.0).year.ago   # quarter year ago
```

NOTE: to use fractions, either the numerator or denominator needs to be a floating point number, otherwise Ruby will automatically cast the answer to an integer, and throw off your math.

Answer (score 3):

You mean sth. like this?

```
if time_ago < Time.now-(1.days+1.hour+1.minute)
    execute me
end
```

Comment: You could also write that as `(1.days+1.hour+1.minute).ago`

Comment: @davidb yours worked, ill switch to normalocity's answer because it's more thorough, to help other people